# Second word message box displaying

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to generate a message box whenever there is more than a word in the particular paragraph selected and the second word should be displayed in it. If there is only a single word then an empty message box should be displayed. Below provided is the code I generated. Is there any alternative method for this?

```
    Sub Second()
        Dim oPara As Paragraph
        Dim Fi As String
        Dim First  As String
        For Each oPara In Selection.Paragraphs
            Fi = oPara.Range.Text
            Dim arr() As String
            arr = VBA.Split(Fi, " ")
            First = arr(1)
        Next
        MsgBox First
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can handle index out of bound errors and can run for multiple paragraph selected.

```
Sub Second()
    Dim oPara As Paragraph
    Dim Fi As String
    Dim First  As String
    For Each oPara In Selection.Paragraphs
        Fi = oPara.Range.Text
        'ignore empty paragraphs
        If Len(Fi) <> 1 Then
            Dim arr() As String
            arr = VBA.Split(Fi, " ")
            On Error GoTo errHandler
            First = arr(1)
            GoTo regular
errHandler:
            First = ""
regular:
            MsgBox First
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```